# Table dynamic center

Tags: html, css

I have a table with 3 cells. The first one is always 50px. The middle one can change, and so can the right one. However, the right one should have higher priority. How is this done?

Here it's working as intended: http://jsfiddle.net/NyQDb/

And here it's squishing the right one: http://jsfiddle.net/NyQDb/1/

The right one can be any number, so a fixed width will not be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `white-space:nowrap;` to the style of the rightmost cell.

http://jsfiddle.net/NyQDb/2/

Answer (score 0):

So you'd like the right one to be larger than the middle one? Then I'd set it's width to a certain percentage. For instance, 50%. But this value mainly depends on your target screen resolution.

By the way: Cell width can be set using CSS as well (`width` property).

Comment: This would not work out, as the cell data is not always the same width